# Find the partial sum of the series and the limit of it $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the partial sum of the series and the limit of it:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{1}{2^n}$

I did $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{1}{2^n} = 0$ so we can not say that the series is divergent.
I tried to use telescopic sum but I do not know what to do with that $\tan$. Can you give me any hint how to write it?

UPDATE

So I did what @lab bhattacharjee recommended and I got that: $\frac{1}{2}\tan x = \frac{1}{\tfrac{1}{\tan\frac{x}{2}}-\tan\frac{x}{2}}\iff\tan x = \frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1+\tan\frac{x}{2}+\tan\frac{x}{2} - 1}{(1+\tan\frac{x}{2})(1-\tan\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{1}{1-\tan\frac{x}{2}}-\frac{1}{1+\tan\frac{x}{2}}.$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

$$\cot x-\tan x =2\cot 2x\iff\dfrac12\tan x=? $$

Put $x=1/2^n, n=1,2,3,\cdots  m$ and add to find  the partial  sum

Finally set $m\to\infty $

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sin{x} & = 2\sin\pars{x \over 2}\cos\pars{x \over 2} =
2\bracks{2\sin\pars{x \over 4}\cos\pars{x \over 4}}\cos\pars{x \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{2}\bracks{2\sin\pars{x \over 8}\cos\pars{x \over 8}}
\cos\pars{x \over 4}\cos\pars{x \over 2}
\\[5mm] & = \cdots =
2^{N}\sin\pars{x \over 2^{N}}\prod_{n = 1}^{N}\cos\pars{x \over 2^{N}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\implies}$

\begin{align}
\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}} & =
N\ln\pars{2} + \ln\pars{\sin\pars{x \over 2^{N}}} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x \over 2^{n}}}
\end{align}

> Derive both sides respect of $\ds{x}$:

\begin{align}
\cot\pars{x} & =
{1 \over 2^{N}}\cot\pars{x \over 2^{N}} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over 2^{n}}\tan\pars{x \over 2^{n}}
\end{align}

> Takes the limit $\ds{N \to \infty}$ with $\ds{x = 1}$:

$$
\bbx{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}}\tan\pars{1 \over 2^{n}} = 1 - \cot\pars{1}} \approx 0.3579
$$